# How to turn a function to string correctly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to rewrite [Greenlet](https://github.com/developit/greenlet/blob/2dd902a9f19fa01ee51b5b8d9fcb5f5af2b630f5/greenlet.js#L13-L32), a library that uses `Blob()` to create a `worker thread` in frontend. I tried to use the same method to convert function to string, but parts of that function disappeared:

```js
  const workerFile = new Blob([`const fn = ${asyncFn};` + (self.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(fn)
  })])
```

It will then renderer:

```
  workerFile.text().then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })

//Returning the following:
/*const fn = async function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};e => {
    console.log(fn);
  }*/
```

**`self.onmessage`** disappeared. How can I stringify it correctly, without using `function.toString()`? What is the missing syntax part I need to know to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why can't you use .toString()?

Answer (score 0):

Looks pointless, and seems like a relatively bad practice. If you already have access to the Server to write such code, you might as well just create a Worker, without greenlet. But, in most Browsers `String+(functionHere);` will give you a String that looks like a function.

```js
console.log(''+(()=>{ /* see it works */ }));
```

Comment: @LoganDevine, not without parentheses... but it would work like `(()=>{ /* see it works */ }).toString()`, but OP is concatenating other things too, I think.

Comment: I have tried to use parentheses as well for wrapping my function, but parts of it has lost as shown in my question. Not sure if it would help, but I am just trying to concat String with function.